# Cannot connect to reporting services from SSMS MSSQL 2017?

Tags: ssms, ms-sql, sql-server-2017

I have installed MSSQL Server  on localhost  although when I try to open
reporting services from ssms v18.3.1 I get the following error message:
Unable to connect to the server at DOMAIN\SSRS. The specified URL might not be valid or there might be a problem with the report server version or configuration. Specify a different URL, or contact your server administrator to verify that the report server runs SQL Server 2008 or later. Additionally, if you are trying to connect to a SharePoint-integrated report server, verify that SharePoint is installed on the server and that the report server uses SharePoint integrated mode. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient).
Does anyone have any idea how to fix this  ?

Other Info might be necessary :
SQL Server Management Studio                        15.0.18183.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        15.0.1487.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.18362.1
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.18362.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                        10.0.18362

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate what version of SQL Server you are running.

Comment: @Ramhound mssql 2017 bro

Comment: Your original title indicates you were using SSMS 2017, which supports multiple versions of SQL Server, but your edit still does not provide the required information I need to answer this question.  *Please edit the body of the question to indicate the exact build of SSMS that you are using.*  Please do not call me "bro", thanks.

Comment: @Ramhound my apologies Sir  , I hope the updated info are enough

Comment: @Ramhound do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever I fixed the problem  in report server configuration manager I changed the web service and web portal url , I created a database from there  , I ran ssms as administrator and voila it worked